# TCL: Read lines from file that contain only relevant words

Tags: tcl

I'm reading file and make some manipulation on the data.
Unfortunately I get the below error message:

unable to alloc 347392 bytes
Abort

Since the file is huge, I want to read only the lines that contain some word (describe in "regexp_or ")

Is there any way to read only the lines that contain "regexp_or" and save the foreach loop?

```
set regexp_or "^Err|warning|Fatal error"
    set file [open [lindex $argv 1] r]
    set data [ read $file ]

foreach line [ split $data "\n" ] {
    if {[regexp [subst $regexp_or] $line]} {
         puts $line
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pull your input through `grep`:

```
set file [open |[list grep -E $regexp_or [lindex $argv 1]] r]
```

But that depends on `grep` being available. To do it completely in Tcl, you can process the file in chunks:

```
set file [open [lindex $argv 1] r]
while {![eof $file]} {
    # Read a million characters
    set data [read $file 1000000]
    # Make sure to only work with complete lines
    append data [gets $file]

    foreach line [lsearch -inline -all -regexp [split $data \n] $regexp_or] {
        puts $line
    }
}
close $file
```

Comment: Of course you can also just process the file line by line using `gets`, but that's probably much slower (Note: I didn't actually measure).

Comment: I'd not expect it to be significantly slower as the buffering's done right, but I've never tested. I also don't have a suitable input corpus for doing such a test…

Comment: I just did a quick test on a 30MB file, counting the matches (there were 3645). The chunked approach was about 12% faster. I ran the test several times for each approach and compared the shortest times of each.